# Referencing an exported constant from within the same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants, export

In react, I have the following file: *constants.js*, containting

```
export const myConstant1 = 'abc';
export const myConstant2 = 'xyz';

export const myObject = {
    myConstant1: 'This is the first constant', // myConstant1 here is NOT recognized
    myConstant2: 'This is the second constant' // myConstant2 here is NOT recognized
}
```

My problem is, I cannot reference `myConstant1` and `myConstant2` from within `myObject`. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use those variable values as the key names in that object? If you are then wrap them in `[]`: `const obj = { [myConstant1]: 'This is...' }`.

Comment: @Andy - This worked like a charm. May I ask you to write this as an answer? So I accept it, and it is for the better good :)